# ENC28j60 Arduino does not show decimals

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, ethernet

I am using ENC28j60 with temp sensor in Arduino uno to see the temperature on the internet, but the problem is that it does not show decimals And shows only the integer.

[Image of Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4YEq.jpg)

```
enter code here#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#define DS18B20 2
 
OneWire ourWire(DS18B20);
DallasTemperature sensors(&ourWire);
float TempDS;

#include "etherShield.h"
#include "ETHER_28J60.h"

static uint8_t mac[6] = {0x54, 0x55, 0x58, 0x10, 0x00, 0x24};                                                       
static uint8_t ip[4] = {192, 168, 0, 15};
static uint16_t port = 80;

ETHER_28J60 ethernet;

void setup(){
  ethernet.setup(mac, ip, port);
  
Serial.begin(9600);
delay(1000);
sensors.begin();
}
 
void loop(){ sensors.requestTemperatures();  TempDS = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);

Serial.print(TempDS);
Serial.println(" C");

  if (ethernet.serviceRequest()){
    ethernet.print("<H1>Hello World</H1>");
    ethernet.print( TempDS );
    ethernet.respond();}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ETHER_28J60's print either takes a char pointer or an integer. You're stuffing a float into it so you're losing the decimals.

Convert your float to a [string](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/)

Comment: Hi . I replaced it, but it does not accept.

ٍError : no matching function for call to 'ETHER_28J60::print(String&)'

Comment: I said string, not Sting. That's a difference. Did you even read the link I provided?